# Python call child static variable from parent static method

Tags: python

How do I basically do this?

```
class Parent:
    Foo = 'Parent food'

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        # want to print whatever the child's Foo is


class Child(Parent):
    Foo = 'Child foo'


# This should print "Child foo"
Child.bar()
```

Comment: You want a _classmethod_, not _staticmethod_. Static methods are stateless by its definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `classmethod` for that

```
class Parent:
    Foo = 'Parent food'

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        print cls.Foo

class Child(Parent):
    Foo = 'Child foo'


Child.bar()
# This will print "Child foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, what you need is a classmethod.

```
class Parent:
    Foo = 'Parent food'

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        print(cls.Foo)
```